# AES java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Iam trying to Encrypt data using AES encryption in my Java application. When I run the code(given below), i get:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:525)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:346)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:806)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1396)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1327)
    at TestEncription.encryptData(TestEncription.java:164)
    at TestEncription.encodeRequest(TestEncription.java:109)
    at TestEncription.main(TestEncription.java:65)
```

---

Code:

```
public String encryptData(String requestData, byte[] sessionKey,
        String messageRefNo) throws Exception {

    SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(sessionKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(symmetricKeyAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(messageRefNo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("Seckey: "+secKey);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey, ivSpec);
    byte[] newData = cipher.doFinal(requestData.getBytes());

    return Base64.encodeBase64String(newData);
}
```

What is that going wrong in here?

Comment: "Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long" you are providing an IV byte[] which is not exactly 16 bytes long.

Comment: What about the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long" you are providing an IV byte[] which is not exactly 16 bytes long.

As @zaph points out, not using a random sequence defeats the purpose of having an IV.

What you should do is provide a random sequence such as

```
Random rand = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
rand.nextBytes(bytes);
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(bytes);
```

Comment: @downvoter any reason?

Comment: The accepted method is to use random bytes for the IV. The IV can be prepended to the encrypted data for use during decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: Works now... Thank You

Comment: Works and is secure are two different things.

Comment: @zaph good point, thank you.

Comment: One question, how come my original code works in windows but not in unbuntu?

Comment: @Abhi1988 possibly the string is not the same length, e.g. line separator on windows is two byte but on Linux it is one.

Comment: Works has a couple of meanings, no errors but incorrect is one meaning. An implementations may handle an IV that is to short by padded or just takes junk bytes past the end, a good implementations will throw an error. There is no standard on how to deal with incorrect input data and parameters.

Comment: @zaph no way to check the byte[] is the right length but not random enough ;)

Comment: Good question, the generally accepted practice is to use a CPRNG to obtain the IV, then the question of random enough is moot. That and pre-pending the IV simplifies the IV usage, they are not static not have to be explicitly passed between encryptor and decryptor..